# how to run D-Bus on windows without console?

Tags: windows, c++11, dbus

I'm porting a linux app on windows and I need **dbus-daemon.exe** running on my win session.

My app and dbus-daemon.exe work fine but the latter still opens a default console and, being not familiar with programming on windows, I don't know how to get rid of it.

Maybe by making it invisible ?

Comment: Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

Windows, by default, opens a console window for executables compiled for the console subsystem (the "subsystem" being essentially a bit of metadata in the Portable Executable format, aka EXE/DLL). So you have at least two options:

1. Compile the `dbus-daemon` for the Windows subsystem, if you're the one doing the compilation. It is a [linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem).
2. Launch the `dbus-daemon` process passing the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) to the relevant API function (probably `CreateProcess`). If you're not using the Windows API directly, look how `CreateProcess` and `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` are exposed in the API you are using. In .NET, for example, it's the [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: thank for the answer, but 1. is excluded (apparently) because dbus-daemon.exe exits immediately after its launch.

Comment: I guess it tries to write to one of the standard streams but it's not available without the console window - try redirecting them, like so: `dbus-daemon.exe > dbus-daemon-stdout.txt 2> dbus-daemon-stderr.txt`

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work e.g. `dbus-daemon --config-file=xx < NUL: > NUL: 2> NUL:` Same results as before...

Comment: Well then, you'll have to debug it (the reason `dbus-daemon` doesn't start) yourself - I suggest redirecting the standard streams to actual files (not `NUL`) and inspecting their contents, and/or debugging the startup under a debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you are right. But I wanted to avoid that :-(